# Unable to set property 'src' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, html, attributes

I am trying to use a button to change a picture on my webpage. When assigning a new value to the `src` attribute I have below error

> Unable to set property 'src' of undefined or null reference

My code is below:

```
<nav>
  <ul class="menuitem">
    <li><a href="#Introduction">Introduction</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Experience">Experience</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Skills">Skills</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Courses">Courses</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Links">Links</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li> 
  </ul>
  <id ="navImg">
    <img src="C:\Users\toffy\Desktop\Course\CMP\Web-based\Worksheets\Tools\cat-selfie.jpg" alt="CatSelfie"style="width:125px;height:75px;" />
  </id>
  <button type="button" onclick="imgUpdate()">Another image</button></button> 
  <script>
    function imgUpdate(){ 
      document.getElementById("navImg").src="C:\Users\toffy\Desktop\Course\CMP\Web-based\Worksheets\Tools\foo.jpg";
    }
  </script>
</nav>
```

Comment: You have the attribute id out of the img tag.

Answer (score 2):

You can fix it by not making up your own HTML tags. `<id>` is not a valid html tag, period. ID is an **ATTRIBUTE** for a tag, it is not tag itself:

```
<img id="navImg" ...>
```

And even if it WAS a tag, you'd be setting the `src` of the `<id>` tag, not the img, and effectively have

```
<id =navImg src="...">
```

Comment: That has been fixed, but when I run it and click the button the picture doesn't change?

Comment: so start debugging, e.g. open your JS console and look for errors.

Comment: There are 0 errors & warnings in my debugging menu under console.

Comment: then make sure that the image you're trying to load actually exists and is reachable.

Comment: Both images are in the same folder.. and I have copied exact location as shown below:

Comment: <script>
function imgUpdate(){
document.getElementById    ('navImg').src'C:\Users\toffy\Desktop\Course\CMP\Web-based\Worksheets\Tools\foo.jpg';

 }
    </script>

Answer (score 1):

After cleaning up a bit of your HTML, the JavaScript code works as expected

```js
function imgUpdate(){
   var img = document.getElementById("navImg");   img.src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UgUs.jpg?s=328&g=1";
}
```

```html
<nav>
  
  <ul class="menuitem">
    <li><a href="#Introduction">Introduction</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Experience">Experience</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Skills">Skills</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Courses">Courses</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Links">Links</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li> 
  </ul>
  <img id="navImg" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/058c57b7a3c00e7d4e8a010ace61889a?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="CatSelfie"style="width:125px;height:75px;" />
  <button type="button" onclick="imgUpdate()">Click for another image</button>
```